# The ST_AsMVT buffer not work in PostGIS 3.0.1 dev

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using PostGIS 3.0.1 dev to generate MVT tiles, and I met a problem that the buffer is not work, below is the code I use. I confirmed the buffer is working for the sub query:

```
select "class", st_asmvtgeom("shape",val_bounding_box,tile_size,water_buffer,false) as "shape" 
        from "{schema}"."osm_water_09_view" 
        where "shape" && val_bounding_box
```

I call `st_astext`to see the text of geometry of st_asmvtgeom and it show the space coordinates which includes the buffer, however the tile generated without any buffer. Is anyone can help me out of that?

```
select into water_mvt 
    st_asmvt(mvt_raw.*,'water',tile_size,'shape')
    from 
    (
        select "class", st_asmvtgeom("shape",val_bounding_box,tile_size,water_buffer,false) as "shape" 
        from "{schema}"."osm_water_09_view" 
        where "shape" && val_bounding_box
    ) mvt_raw where "shape" is not null;
```

Comment: Just post an update here: The `val_bounding_box` should make a buffer too in the where clause.